# Updating CSS Style During Sub Execution in VBS

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am writing an HTA in VBScript to populate an excel workbook with different sheets depending on data from a source workbook. I've written an accompanying HTA with multiple divs that have their display set to none at a button press to bring up various types of input before giving the user a button that says "Run" to begin the workbook population. However, I am having an issue that I cannot both change the div's visibility AND run the population sub at the click of the Run button.

To illustrate, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="panel1">
    [div content]
    <input type="button" id="panel1-next" onClick="ChangeFrame">
</div>
<div id="panel2">
    [div content]
    <input type="button" id="panel2-next" onClick="ChangeFrame">
</div>
<div id="panel3">
    [div content]
    <input type="button" id="panel3-run" onClick="ChangeFrame">
</div>
<div id="panel-end">
    [div content]
    <input type="button" id="panel-end">
</div>
```

The `ChangeFrame` sub looks like this

```
Sub ChangeFrame()
    Select case window.event.srcelement.id
        Case "panel1-next"
            panel1.style.display = "none"
            panel2.style.display = "block"
        case "panel2-next"
            panel2.style.display = "none"
            panel3.style.display = "block"
        case "panel3-run"
            panel3.style.display = "none"
            panel-end.style.display = "block"
            Call Main()
        case else
            MsgBox window.event.srcelement.id & " Something broke"
    End Select
End Sub
```

With this code, I would like `ChangeFrame`, when the `panel3-run` button is pressed, to first update the CSS for `panel3` and `panel-end` so that while `Main` is running, the user is shown the content of `panel-end`. However, the issue I'm having is that the CSS for `panel3` and `panel-end` is only visually updated AFTER `Main` has finished it its entirety, instead of before.

I am also having this issue elsewhere in the code when I am trying to make a progress bar that shows how much of the source data has been evaluated and made into a new sheet. In `panel-end` I have the following HTML

```
<div id="bar-outline">
    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
#bar-outline {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#progress-bar {
    width:0px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

to create the blank progress bar within the `panel-end` greater div. I would like the progress bar to grow in width with each loop in `Main`, which looks like this:

```
Sub Main()
    [code to locate source file]
    [code to create and save destination file]

    For i = 0 to 9
         [code to find string from array(i) and make a new sheet with string name]
         [code to populate destination sheet(i+1) with all instances of the data that match the string from array(i)]
         progress-bar.style.width = (i/10)*198
    Next
End Sub
```

The idea is that after every iteration of the `For` loop, the width of the `progress-bar` div will grow by 10% of `bar-outline`'s width, minus two pixels for the 1px border. However, I have the same issue as with switching between `panel3` and `panel-end`: the `progress-bar` div's visual appearance won't update until after all of `Main` has been completed, which completed nullifies the reasoning for having the progress bar in the first place.

I have two questions that I would like answered. First, how exactly does the code execute in VBScript so that the CSS and HTML are only visually updated after the sub is finished? And second, what are ways in which I can get around this?

Comment: Yes, that's how the DOM works, all the script will be executed first, and after that the window is re-rendered. Usually this is even desirable behavior. You can't force re-rendering during script execution, but you can call the next function with `window.setTimeout`, and then finish the current execution.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu! That is the same thing I'm asking. However, I'd like a bit of clarification just to make sure I understand. Calling `window.setTimeout` will delay the execution of the function passed to it - in my case, `Main` - while the rest of the function - `ChangeFrame` - is executed. `ChangeFrame` will finish, and THEN `Main` will start being executed because of `window.setTimeout`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and in the meanwhile, the updated DOM is rendered, immediately after `ChangeFrame` has finished.